# Diffusion equation solution using Laplace transform

Tags: heat-equation, laplace-transform, green-function

Consider the operator 
$$
L=k\frac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{\partial }{\partial t}
$$ with domain $D(L)={u} \in \Bbb R \times [0,+\infty )$, initial value $u(x,0)=g(x), \forall x\in \Bbb R$, and the following asymptotic conditions
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty } u(x,t)&=0\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} u_{x}(x,t)&=0 
\end{split}\quad\forall t\geq 0
$$

(a) Prove that the solution of the equation $Lu=f(x,t)$ can be written as: $$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{\infty }\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty}G^{*}(x,t;\xi ,\tau )f(\xi ,\tau )d\xi d\tau -\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }G^{*}(x,t;\xi ,0))g(\xi )d\xi$$

(b) $G(x,t;\xi ,\tau )=G^{*}(\xi ,\tau ;x,t )$  where $G$ and $G^{*}$ are the Green's functions of $L$ and his adjoint $L^{*}$ respectively.

(c) Using the above find the solutions of the equation $Lu=f(x,t)$ using the Laplace integral transform.
$$L\left \{ \delta (\tau -\alpha ) \right \}(s)=e^{-as}\text{ and }L\left \{ H(\tau -\alpha) \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau -\alpha }}e^{-\frac{c}{\tau -\alpha }} \right \}(s)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{s}}e^{-\alpha s-2\sqrt{cs}}.$$
I have already answered (a) and (b) and I am having difficulties with the Laplace transform. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like homework (especially given the break-down into (a), (b), and (c)).  If it is, then it doesn't belong here.